# Web APIs or libraries to find the URL format for searching a given site?

Tags: api, url, search, hook

I'm writing an app with a feature that will let the user choose from a list of common websites, then type a query in an entry box and hit "search." So I need to be able to get the URL format to make a search on a given website. For example, Google is `http://www.google.com/search?q=`**x**, while Amazon is `http://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=`**x**.

My hope is that I won't have to build a list of these formats myself. Are there any libraries for doing this, or sites that provide an API? The web app launcher [YubNub](http://yubnub.org/) has commands to search many sites, but they don't seem to have a public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenSearch documents](http://www.opensearch.org/) were designed to save you from having to build this yourself - there are a number of [directories of OpenSearch documents for many sites](http://www.opensearch.org/Community/OpenSearch_search_engine_directories).

For most purposes I use [the Mycroft project from MozDev](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/) to get lists of popular sites' search documents.